# How to write select case in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

how can i write the select case statement in t-sql ? My Code below doesn't work, help
I just want the match case, insert statement start insert the value into table.

```
SET @DayName = dbo.GetWeekDayNameOfDate(@SaleDate)
      SELECT 
            CASE @DayName
                WHEN 'Sunday' THEN 
                    INSERT INTO Tmp_Data(ProductID,ProductName,Sunday,NetProfit) 
                    VALUES(@ProductId,@ProductName,@Qty,@Profit);
                WHEN 'Monday' THEN 
                    INSERT INTO Tmp_Data(ProductID,ProductName,Monday,NetProfit) 
                    VALUES(@ProductId,@ProductName,@Qty,@Profit);
                WHEN 'Tuesday' THEN 
                    INSERT INTO Tmp_Data(ProductID,ProductName,Tuesday,NetProfit) 
                    VALUES(@ProductId,@ProductName,@Qty,@Profit);
                WHEN 'Wednesday' THEN 
                    INSERT INTO Tmp_Data(ProductID,ProductName,Wednesday,NetProfit) 
                    VALUES(@ProductId,@ProductName,@Qty,@Profit);
                WHEN 'Thursday' THEN 
                    INSERT INTO Tmp_Data(ProductID,ProductName,Thursday,NetProfit) 
                    VALUES(@ProductId,@ProductName,@Qty,@Profit);
                WHEN 'Friday' THEN 
                    INSERT INTO Tmp_Data(ProductID,ProductName,Friday,NetProfit) 
                    VALUES(@ProductId,@ProductName,@Qty,@Profit);
                WHEN 'Saturday' THEN 
                    INSERT INTO Tmp_Data(ProductID,ProductName,Saturday,NetProfit) 
                    VALUES(@ProductId,@ProductName,@Qty,@Profit);
            END
```

Comment: You can\t put an `INSERT` inside a `CASE` clause.

Comment: I would change Tmp_data's structure to (ProductID, ProductName, Qty, NetProfit, DayOfWk), where DayOfWk accepts integer values ranging from 1-7, or something similar. This would make it much easier to query and maintain.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I agree with @John Dewey's comment - you shouldn't have a column for each weekday, but rather a single column that has the weekday. Assuming for a moment that you can't fix the broken schema, next you need to understand that `CASE` is an expression that returns a value, not a control of flow statement like it works in some other languages. This means you can't say `CASE THEN something THEN go do something else`.

Here is one way to write your statement that will reduce at least some of the redundancy you're attempting:

```
SET @DayName = dbo.GetWeekDayNameOfDate(@SaleDate);

INSERT dbo.Tmp_Data(ProductID,ProductName,NetProfit,
    Sunday,Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday,Saturday)
    SELECT @ProductId,@ProductName,@Profit,
      CASE @DayName WHEN 'Sunday'    THEN @Qty END,
      CASE @DayName WHEN 'Monday'    THEN @Qty END,
      CASE @DayName WHEN 'Tuesday'   THEN @Qty END,
      CASE @DayName WHEN 'Wednesday' THEN @Qty END,
      CASE @DayName WHEN 'Thursday'  THEN @Qty END,
      CASE @DayName WHEN 'Friday'    THEN @Qty END,
      CASE @DayName WHEN 'Saturday'  THEN @Qty END;
```

You could also also build the statement in dynamic SQL. Not the way I would prefer, just including that option for brevity.

```
SET @DayName = dbo.GetWeekDayNameOfDate(@SaleDate);

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(4000);

SET @sql = N'INSERT dbo.Tmp_Data(ProductID,ProductName,NetProfit,' 
    + @DayName + ') SELECT ' 
      + CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), @ProductId) +','
      + '''' + @ProductName + ''','
      + CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), @Profit) + ','
      + CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), @Qty) + ';';

PRINT @sql;
-- EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Comment: I think you need some GROUP BY stuff in your first query or a PIVOT or a CROSS JOIN to something with 7 rows, one for each day of the week. Or something.

Comment: @ErikE could you explain? Did you try the query? Did it not produce the results you were expecting? You know there's just one row being inserted right?

Comment: You're right. I didn't understand what he was doing. Sorry to bother you! What an *interesting* table design.

Comment: Yep, interesting is one word for it. :-)

Answer (score -4):

Please try this.

```
SET @DayName = dbo.GetWeekDayNameOfDate(@SaleDate)
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN @DayName = 'Sunday' THEN 
            INSERT INTO Tmp_Data(ProductID,ProductName,Sunday,NetProfit) 
            VALUES(@ProductId,@ProductName,@Qty,@Profit);
        WHEN @DayName = 'Monday' THEN 
            INSERT INTO Tmp_Data(ProductID,ProductName,Monday,NetProfit) 
            VALUES(@ProductId,@ProductName,@Qty,@Profit);
        WHEN @DayName= 'Tuesday' THEN 
            INSERT INTO Tmp_Data(ProductID,ProductName,Tuesday,NetProfit) 
            VALUES(@ProductId,@ProductName,@Qty,@Profit);
        WHEN @DayName= 'Wednesday' THEN 
            INSERT INTO Tmp_Data(ProductID,ProductName,Wednesday,NetProfit) 
            VALUES(@ProductId,@ProductName,@Qty,@Profit);
        WHEN @DayName= 'Thursday' THEN 
            INSERT INTO Tmp_Data(ProductID,ProductName,Thursday,NetProfit) 
            VALUES(@ProductId,@ProductName,@Qty,@Profit);
        WHEN @DayName= 'Friday' THEN 
            INSERT INTO Tmp_Data(ProductID,ProductName,Friday,NetProfit) 
            VALUES(@ProductId,@ProductName,@Qty,@Profit);
        WHEN @DayName= 'Saturday' THEN 
            INSERT INTO Tmp_Data(ProductID,ProductName,Saturday,NetProfit) 
            VALUES(@ProductId,@ProductName,@Qty,@Profit);
    END
```

Comment: Whoever upvoted deserves to have their computer licence revoked.

Comment: The case syntax in itself is just fine and doesn't need correcting